# Quotient Ring example issue

Tags: quotient-spaces, quotient-group, quotient-set

I am currently learning about lattices and came across a Mr.Bill Buchanan video that explains the Ring-LWE problem. I understand how modulo works and quite understand the math behind it.

However, I got stuck by the system of equations that are used in the video!

A = (4 + x + 11x^2 + 10x^3)

S = (6 + 9x + 11x^2 + 11x^3)

e = (0 - x + x^2 + x^3)

what is the result of B = A*S + e over the ring Z13[x]/[x^4+1]

He got the answer: 10 + 5x + 10x^2 + 7x^3

How did he get to the final answer using the provided quotient ring?

Can someone please explain in step-by-step solution?

Thank you in advance for helping me understand.

Here is a screenshot from the actual video: [the actual equation system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66xLl.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should write the question in such a way that it's not necessary to see the video or the image to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

By @coffeemath "To begin, multiply and add the polynomials in the usual way. Then you will have a sixth degree result. Two things are involved to get the result in Z13[x]. First, the degree 4,5,6 terms can be combined with lower degree since x^4=-1, x^5=-x, and x^6=-x^2. second, coefficients may be reduced mod 13."

Thank you very much for your help. Your comment solved the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A.H. Welcome... hope you were able to arrive at correct answer.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes I was.... Many thanks my friend